# Двусмысленность в деепричастных оборотах

Tags: деепричастный-оборот, смысл, деепричастия

Согласно теории деепричастие или деепричастный оборот означает добавочное действие, сопутствующее основному действию, выраженному сказуемым. Обычно эти два действия независимы друг от друга.
Но я нередко замечаю, что деепричастный оборот иногда не просто означает добавочное действие, а очень сильно связан со сказуемым и выполняет уже немного другую функцию в предложении. Акцент смещается на деепричастный оборот. Даже сложно назвать такой деепричастный оборот обстоятельством, хочется отнести его к сказуемому.

Например:
**Он смотрит телевизор, говоря что-то маме** (добавочное действие).
**Он обижает его, говоря такие вещи** (обижает тем, что говорит такие вещи).
Смысл: высказывание таких вещей обижает его.

Поэтому иногда в тексте немного непонятен смысл фраз.
**Он выполняет его просьбу, записывая на листке имена клиентов.**
Просьба заключается в записи имён?
Или он выполняет какую-то просьбу и параллельно записывает имена?
Предложение придуманное, но вы уловили суть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Деепричастный оборот — **это полупредикативная конструкция**, которая является аналогом придаточного предложения.  (Деепричастный оборот обозначает действие, добавочное по отношению к основному действию, выраженному сказуемым).

А придаточные предложения могут иметь различные значения, которые **определяются с помощью   союзов (или других слов)**, например:

Он выполняет его просьбу, **когда** записывает на листке имена клиентов. Он выполняет его просьбу, **и при этом** записывает на листке имена клиентов.

Так как у деепричастного оборота таких возможностей нет, то может возникнуть **неоднозначность смысла**, устранить которую  помогает **контекст.**

Но это обычное явление для русского языка. К примеру, у нас   много омонимов, многозначных слов, смысл которых также устанавливается по контексту.

Answer (score 2):

> «Он выполняет его просьбу, записывая на листке имена клиентов» Просьба заключается в записи имён, или он выполняет какую-то просьбу и параллельно записывает имена?

Это зависит от контекста. Если в более широком контексте двусмысленность остаётся, это означает недоработку автора/редактора. Следует отметить, что двусмысленность во второстепенных деталях может не влиять на основное содержание текста. Например, автор может не посчитать нужным уточнять, о чьих клиентах шла речь.